# Splitting a string then adding it to another variable and getting undefined included

Tags: javascript

I have a string that uses a & for a delimiter and I need take that string, split it and then add it to another variable with line breaks. No problem.

The problem is that when I am adding each split string to the other variable am getting the undefined keyword added to my string.

The is

```
let sentence = "Hi there & How are you & today?";
let sentenceSplit = sentence.split('& ');
let comp;

for(i=0;i<sentenceSplit.length; i++){
comp = sentenceSplit[i] + comp + "\n";

}
console.log(comp);
```

and this is how it looks

```
undefinedHi there 
How are you 
today?
```

and it should be

```
Hi there 
How are you 
today?
```

How do I stop the undefined keyword from appearing in my new string?

Comment: do you have `Hi there undefined` or as listed above `undefined Hi there` ?

Comment: @82Tuskers, as listed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise the `comp` variable as empty string (`''`), then you can concatenate to it.

You also seem to be concatenating in an order, it should be:

```
comp = comp + sentenceSplit[i] + '\n';
```

or, more simply,

```
comp += sentenceSplit[i] + '\n';
```

Making the final code:

```js
let sentence = "Hi there & How are you & today?";
let sentenceSplit = sentence.split('& ');
let comp = '';

for (let i = 0; i < sentenceSplit.length; i++){
    comp += sentenceSplit[i] + "\n";
}
console.log(comp);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I didn't even think about initializing the comp variable, I made a mental note of that. As soon as it allows me I'll accept this answer

Comment: @Chris Awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize comp variable. Because comp variable is undefined when you are trying to add it to the 0th element of your sting array.

```
Set comp = ""
```

Before running the loop.